# static переменная

Tags: java

```
public class Duck {
    int duckCount = 0;
    public Duck(){
        duckCount++;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duck duck = new Duck();
        Duck duck1 = new Duck();
        System.out.println(duck.duckCount);
        System.out.println(duck1.duckCount);
    }
}
```

Здесь в консоли 2 раза выйдет единица (1):
1
1

Не пойму в чем суть если переменную duckCount не помечаем static то значение в консоле выходит 1 у всех, а если static то 2 в данном примере

```
public class Duck {
    static int duckCount = 0;
    public Duck(){
        duckCount++;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duck duck = new Duck();
        Duck duck1 = new Duck();
        System.out.println(duck.duckCount);
        System.out.println(duck1.duckCount);
    }
}
```

А тут выйдет в консоле:
2
2
Из-за статика не пойму почему

Как я правильно понял если переменная не статичная значит для каждого экземпляра класса будет своя переменная `duckCount`, а если статичная то общая для всех экземпляров, но в данном примере зачем тогда создавать экземпляры класса если вызываем нашу статичную переменную через Класс.переменная?

Comment: я вам гигантский ответ написал на ваш предыдущий вопрос, а вы его удалили... там я это рассказывал. Переписывать не буду (((  Почитайте [тут](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntax.level06.lecture06). Может быть поймете

Comment: @Dred разве можно удалить вопрос, на который получен ответ?

Comment: Для ответа на ваш вопрос вам нужно книгу читать по Java, первые главы.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, не знаю, ему в комментариях ответили, а я в это время писал ответ, а когда нажал отправить, было написано, вопрос удален

Comment: @Dred :// Печально

Comment: Экземпляры класса создаются не для того, чтобы вызвать их переменные, а для того, чтобы с ними работать. Поэтому вопрос "_зачем тогда создавать экземпляры класса если вызываем нашу статичную переменную через Класс.переменная_" довольно бессмысленный. Можете вызывать через Duck.duckCount, без создания экземляров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберем Ваш пример.

```
public class Duck {
    int duckCount = 0;
    public Duck(){
        duckCount++;
    }
}
```

Тут у нас есть класс, где есть переменная `duckCount` = 0, и есть конструктор счетчик `Duck`

```
        Duck duck = new Duck();
        Duck duck1 = new Duck();
        System.out.println(duck.duckCount);
        System.out.println(duck1.duckCount);
```

Тут мы создаем два экземпляра нашего класса, и при этом вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, где мы к новой переменной 0 - применяем счетчик +1
В таком же примере, только со статичной переменной происходит все то же самое, только вот новая переменная не создается, а вызывается та же, к которой все равно применяется конструктор(два раза), ведь мы создали экземпляр класса. Зачем же тогда создавать экземпляр класса? Тут ответить мне сложно, т.к. это порой требует задача, со временем поймете.

И настоятельно рекомендую читать книгу, к примеру Java-8-Полное руководство, автор Шилдт

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, правда Шилдта на русском мне тут посоветовали не читать, перевод не очень говорят опытные ребята, а на английском у меня чтение слабое технических книг

Comment: @MikeMclaren возможно, кто читал несколько книг может сделать выводы лучше, я читаю Шилдта, не могу сказать что книга не очень

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/nP27RE

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
  static class Duck {
    static int duckCount = 0;
    int duckIndex;

    public Duck(){
      duckIndex = ++duckCount;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Duck duck = new Duck();
    Duck duck1 = new Duck();
    System.out.println(duck.duckIndex);
    System.out.println(duck1.duckIndex);
  }
}
```